# I have a small problem with long division when dividing polynomials of the same degree

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was doing long division with $x^2 + 1$, and $3x^2+5$. (the second polynomial is the quotient).
the problem I've found is related to dividing two polynomials of the same degree. Even if I know that the quotient is always a constant and the remainder is a polynomial of one degree less than the dividend, I still have problem when performing this long division, meaning:

$x^2+0+1\space /\space 3x^2+5$

x^2 is contained in 3x^2 3 times, so I write 3 in the quotient.

then, I perform multiplication between the quotient and the divisor. $3 * 3x^2 = 9x^2$, and $3*5 = 15$. I write them below the dividend.
Now, I subtract the dividend with the things I have below.

but, it's an infinite loop, because the degree doesn't change no matter how long I divide.

Comment: When you multiply the quotient and the divisor, isn't the divisor $x^2 + \cdots$ rather than $3x^2 + 5$? Multiplying $x^2 + \cdots$ by $3$ yields $3x^2 + \cdots$ which will cancel with the leading term of $3x^2+5$ when subtracting.

Comment: @angryavian no, the dividend is x2+0+1, because in the integral I have it in the numerator.

Comment: Then the quotient is $1/3$, no?

Comment: I think the quotient is 3, because as I wrote above x^2 is contained in 3x^2 3 times; am I wrong?

Comment: In general you usually ask "how many times is the divisor contained in the dividend," rather than "how many times is the dividend contained in the divisor."

Comment: Terminology: $\dfrac{\text{dividend}}{\text{divisor}} = \text{quotient}$

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini It may be easier to see if you write it $\,\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+5/3}\,$. Then you can get rid of the fractions at the end.

Comment: Why did you write it as $x^2 + 0 + 1/3x^2 + 5$ instead of $\frac {3^2 + 5}{x^2 + 1}$?

Comment: Why did you write it as $x^2 + 0 + 1/3x^2 + 5$ instead of $\frac {3x^2 + 5}{x^2 + 1}$? You only get quotient of $3$ if you are diving $3x^2 + 5$ by $x^2 + 1$ and then you should multiply $x^2+ 1$ by $3$; not $3x^2 + 5$.  If you are trying to divide $x^2 +1$ by $3x^2 + 5$ then the quotient is $\frac 13$ and you should multiply $3x^2+ 5$ by $\frac 13$.  Either way, your $x^2$ terms vanish.

Comment: "because as I wrote above x^2 is contained in 3x^2 3 times; am I wrong?"  You are right if you are dividing $3x^2 + 5$ but $x^2 +1$ which is *not* what you wrote.  If you wrote $x^2 + 1$ divided by $3x^2 + 5$ then the quotient is $\frac 13$ because $3x^2$ is contained in $x^2$ $\frac 13$ times.  If you are dividing by $x^2 + 1$ then you are supposed to multiply $x^2 +1$ by $3$; not $3x^2 + 5$ by $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing what you dividing *into* with what you are dividing *by* and you are taking the quotient, $3$, and multiply it by what you are dividing *into*; not what you are dividing *by*.  You must multiply the quotient by what you are dividing *by*.

Question 1:  $\frac {3x^2+ 5}{x^2 + 1}$ then we divide $x^2$ into $3x^2$ and get a quotient of $3$.  So we multiply the denominator, $x^2 + 1$ by $3$ to get $3(x^2+1)=3x^2 + 3$.  Then you subtract $(3x^2 + 5)-(3x^2 + 3) = 2$.  Now you have the remainder.

So $\frac {3x^2 + 5}{x^2 + 1} = 3 + \frac 2{x^2 + 1}$.

Question 2: $\frac {x^2 + 1}{3x^2 + 5}$ then we divide $3x^2$ into $x^2$ and we get a quotient of $\frac 13$ (because $3x^2$ goes into $x^2$ a total of $\frac 13$ times).  So we multiply the denominator, $3x^3 + 5$ by $\frac 13$ to got $\frac 13(3x^2 + 5) = x^2 + \frac 53$.  Then we subtract $(x^2 + 1)-(x^2 + \frac 53)= -\frac 23$.  Now we have a remainedr of $-\frac 23$.

So $\frac {x^2+1}{3x^2 + 5} = \frac 13 -\frac {\frac 23}{3x^2 + 5}$.